# Window.scrollTo is undefined in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to do a simple window.scrollTo(0,0) on a button click. I want it to just move the window to the top. Unfortunately the `window.scrollTo(0,0)` does nothing with the GUI.

I suspect it has something to do with React and the structure of the application.

```
scrollToTop: function() {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}
```

[image: window undefined]

Do I have to do it in another way with react or is there something I have missed?

Comment: In your example from the console, it *does* exist (otherwise it would have thrown a `TypeError` rather than returning `undefined`) - we'll need a bit more information about your actual setup to help debug this.

Comment: I am not certain what information is relevant to this matter due to that I have not encountered such a problem before.  I can not find it in the list of functions when printing out ```window```, but as you were saying, the function is there. It is not throwing any ```TypeError```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the problem was that I had a fixed position on my main container.

```
main-container {
   position: fixed; // Should use either static or relative
}
```

This made the window keep its position "fixed", which meant that `window.scrollTo()`would not change the position.

So be careful using `position: fixed;`unless you want the element to stick in the viewport. (like a header)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and found out this CSS code will also block the scrollTo() function.

```
body, html {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```